# Array multiplying data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't figure out why my data is acting strangely when storing to the array. Basically what I have is a note section, I'm trying to implement a feature that lets you edit the notes and it will save the note while you edit it.

I did this by when the note is focused it saves the current note typed, then when typing a new note it will look for the old note in the array and replace it with the new one. This seems to work fine for the first one, but when I click another note after the first one it replaces the first notes data with the newest note.

The image is the console log of the array. What I did: Added 4 notes, ABCD, added 1 to A, 2 to B, 3 to C, and 4 to B. This is what the console log showed each time, as you can see 1a worked fine, then 2b replaced 1a, then 3c replaced the other two and so on.

I have a feeling this the workflow of how I have written it but can't figure it out

[image: The console log of the array.]

html:

```
<div id="icon-wrapper">
            <div id="notes-icon" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></div>
            <div id="bg-left" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></div>
            <div id="bg-right" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
            <div id="refresh" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></div>
            <div id="pin" class="icons"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="time-wrapper">
            <div id="time"></div>
            <div id="date"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Create a note">
        </div>

        <div id="notes-wrapper">
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.note>span', function(e){
        var storedNote = $(this).text();
        var storedNoteIndex = notes.indexOf(storedNote);
        console.log('Stored Note: ' + storedNote);
        console.log('Index of Stored Note: ' + storedNoteIndex);
        console.log(notes)
        $(document).on('keyup', '.note>span', function (e) { //edit notes
            var newNote = $(this).text();
            if(newNote != "" && newNote != " " && newNote.charAt(0) != " ") {
                /*if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {

                }*/
                var newNote = $(this).text();
                notes.splice(storedNoteIndex, 1, newNote);
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'notes':notes});
                console.log(notes);
            }
            else{
                notes.splice(storedNoteIndex, 1);
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'notes':notes});
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: You're adding the "keyup" handler *inside* the "focus" handler. That means that every time the field gets focus, you'll add *another copy* of the event handler. The `.on()` API does not remove any existing handlers.

Comment: Also you never check whether `storedNoteIndex` is `-1` - what clues have you gotten from the `console.log()` output?

Comment: @Pointy I thought it was this but wasn't sure - quite new to this stuff, this is my first project. How can I store the note that is already in the span and use it within the save function to splice the array? - If I have 4 notes and I make 5 edits then I get -1 from the array, like it's incrementing

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a really silly mistake! I had the keyup function acting on all '.note>span' rather than just the one that in focus..

changing

`$(document).on('keyup', '.note>span', function (e) {`

to

```
$(this).keyup(function (e) {
```

feel a bit stupid for this one!